# Sql query duplicate column with different effective start date

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table x_person and x_person_name. with structure as :

```
x_person

eff_start_date eff_end_date   person_number 

01-jan-1990     31-dec-4712     2
01-feb-1990     31-dec-4712     2

01-jan-1990     31-dec-4712     1


x_person_name


eff_start_date eff_end_date   person_number  name

01-jan-1990     31-dec-4712     2             freida 
01-feb-1990     31-dec-4712     2             sam

01-jan-1990     31-dec-4712     1             isha
```

Now i want to check in these two tables for same employee have same effective start dates . for those who dont i created a query

```
select * from 
(
select distinct min(x.Effective_Start_Date) over(partition by x.person_number) Effective_Start_Date_name, y.Effective_Start_Date,x.person_number
from  x_person_name x,x_person y where 
x.person_number=y.person_number 
) 
where Effective_Start_Date_name <> Effective_Start_Date;
```

but this query will not work for example for person number 2 though they are 2 different ppl and have 2 differnet records in x_person. but still it is comng in the output.

Output  I am getting

```
effective_start_date  y.effective_start_date person_number
01-jan-1990            01-feb-1990            2
```

Whereas this shouldnt be coming.

Comment: If I understand well, with your sample data you should have no rows returned, correct?

Comment: What output do you expect and what is your current output?

Comment: @Utsav- i have edited my anser pls cehck now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need the rows from `x_person` not matching `x_person_name`, maybe this can help:

```
select *
from x_person p
  left outer join x_person_name pn
  ON (
      p.person_number = pn.person_number and
      p.eff_start_date = pn.eff_start_date
     )
where pn.person_number is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x_perosn(eff_start_date, eff_end_date, person_number)
     as (select to_date('01-jan-1990'), to_date('31-dec-4712'), 2 from dual
         union all
         select to_date('01-feb-1990'), to_date('31-dec-4712'), 2 from dual
         union all
         select to_date('01-jan-1990'), to_date('31-dec-4712'), 1 from dual)
   , x_person_name(eff_start_date
                 , eff_end_date
                 , person_number
                 , name)
     as (select to_date('01-jan-1990'), to_date('31-dec-4712'), 2, 'freida' from dual
         union all
         select to_date('01-feb-1990'), to_date('31-dec-4712'), 2, 'sam' from dual
         union all
         select to_date('01-jan-1990'), to_date('31-dec-4712'), 1, 'isha' from dual)                                        
select * from (         
select  min(eff_start_date) over( partition by person_number) ed,y.* from x_person_name y
        ) t1 where not exists (select 1 from x_perosn where person_number= t1.person_number and ed = eff_start_date)
```

I think you are looking for something called, anti-join. Retrun only rows from  table1 which there are no rows in table2.